# nslookup not work correctly

Tags: networking, dns, nslookup

Hi I'm learning about nslookup but when I try with this command (`nslookup -type=NS cam.ac.uk`) my terminal returns this...

```
Server:     8.8.8.8
Address:    8.8.8.8#53

Non-authoritative answer:
cam.ac.uk   nameserver = authdns0.csx.cam.ac.uk.
cam.ac.uk   nameserver = ns2.ic.ac.uk.
cam.ac.uk   nameserver = dns0.cl.cam.ac.uk.
cam.ac.uk   nameserver = sns-pb.isc.org.
cam.ac.uk   nameserver = dns0.eng.cam.ac.uk.

Authoritative answers can be found from:
```

But when I try in other notebook the same command nslookup returns `Authoritative answers can be found from`, I am seeking how solution this, but I don't found the solution, any ideas???

Sorry for my english, I am learning this.

Answer (score 0):

Two observations to your test:

If you dont specify the DNS Server you want to ask, the nslookup will try your default DNS. This of course can be different between two computers.

For the sake of the test validation and really know who is responding your query, is a lot better to specify it, like this (asking 8.8.8.8 server):

```
nslookup -type=NS cam.ac.uk. 8.8.8.8
```

Another point in your query is the name, is always better to add the trailing dot, that way you will have an absolute **[FQDN](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/FQDN)**, avoiding your computer to take it as relative and do funny things like adding your country domain extension at the end.